# workers churn through a vast mechanism

Tags: word-meaning

> The Human Cost of Amazon’s Employment Machine
> Hundreds of thousands of **workers churn through a vast mechanism** that hires, monitors, disciplines and fires. During the pandemic, the operation lurched.
> Source: [NYTimes](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2021/06/15/us/amazon-workers.html)

Does "workers churn through a vast mechanism" mean "workers were moved forcibly through a vast mechanism"?

The word "churn" means "to move something, especially a liquid, with great force"(Cambridge Dictionary). So I guess "churn" here as "be moved forcibly", not sure whether I am on the right track?

Comment: Yes, you're on the right track. It's a slightly unusual construction, partly because almost certainly those workers are being seen as ***passive*** "subjects" (linguistically, "patients" rather than "agents"), so a more careful writer might have indicated that by *Hundreds of thousands of workers **are churned** through a vast mechanism...* Well, I would, anyway, but that doesn't necessarily mean I'm a more "careful" writer than your cited NY Times hack.

Comment: A machine churns butter, by stirring or agitating the milk. So, here the workers are like butter being churned.

Comment: @FumbleFingers There is nothing wrong with the sentence, in fact. It is nicely constructed. Hacks work for The Sun, not the NYT.

Comment: @Lambie: Well, I could have guessed *you* would make a different stylistic choice to me! :) But I note that you yourself expressed it as passive *the workers are like butter **being churned***, rather than the "active" version in the NYT piece. If that "deliberate, volitional" aspect of the workers was intended, perhaps ***swarm*** would have been a "better" verb.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Here, they churn through just means they move through in an agitated manner, not calmly, as if they are butter. I think it is very effective.

Comment: This passive hide-the-guilty-party sort of writing is a NYT hallmark (see "cycle of violence" to describe Palestinians attacking Israelis for example). That it's vague and/or sloppy is just a matter of course. It's really psuedo-intellectualism at its finest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb **churn** is used here in its intransitive form, meaning it has no object. The workers are not *being* churned, or churning anything else; they simply *are churning.* The intended definition is along the lines of "to produce, proceed with, or experience violent motion or agitation" ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/churn)), or "to move or shake in agitation, as a liquid or any loose matter" ([Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/churn)).

To put it another way: the writer wants the reader to picture a mass of workers so large ("hundreds of thousands") that it is hard to notice the movement of any single individual. Instead, you see the movement of the entire crowd at once, which behaves more like a liquid. This crowd-as-liquid metaphor is fairly common; you might describe a mass of people as *pouring* or *streaming* through a gateway.

Are the workers are being *moved forcibly*? It's unclear. When we talk about ocean waves churning among the rocks on the shore, we know that the rocks are not moving. Rather, the ocean rushes towards the rocks, and then bounces off them and gets deflected in different directions. The "vast mechanism" described by the author might take an active role in moving the workers, or it might take a more reactive role, like those rocks. It's not important. The main idea is that there are a lot of workers, and their movements are somewhat chaotic or imperfectly controlled. (If the author wanted us to picture the movements of the workers as orderly or well-controlled, he might have written that "the workers *pump* through a vast mechanism" instead.)